# javascript loop getElementById

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a page containing a lots of text boxes with an incremental id. I'd like to read all these IDs and display them using javascript.

HTML page that looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="item1" value="111" ></input>
<input type="text" id="item2" value="222" ></input>
<input type="text" id="item3" value="333" ></input>
```

and a javascript part:

```
for (var i=1; i<3; i++){
    var values = parseInt(document.getElementById('item' + i).value);
    document.write(values);
}
```

I can't figure out why but only the first ID is displayed then firefox return an error (in the debugging console sysing: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Thanks for your help !

Romain

Comment: When "the first ID is displayed", what does the page look like? Is it a white screen with just "111" in the upper left corner?

Comment: On JSFiddle looks OK: http://jsfiddle.net/xFZz8/

Comment: BTW: `for(var i=1; i<3; i++)` will write only 2 elements

Comment: @romain the likely problem is that `document.write()` obliterates the entire page when it's called after the page has completed.

Comment: Isn't document.write() considered to be a bad practice ?

Comment: on my page I only have a 111 displayed and the mentioned error. What can I use instead of document.write if I want to display a for loop output ?

Comment: When `document.write()` is used on a document that is already loaded, it clears the current document and starts a new blank one, thus wiping out your current DOM.  Chance are you don't want to use `document.write()` here at all.

Answer (score 5):

`document.write` is causing the problem, remove it outside the loop and it should work. Also, your `for` loop definition only loops for 2 elements, not the 3th one ...

```
var values = [], i = 0;
for (; i < 4; i += 1) {
    values.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('item' + i).value, 10));
}

document.write(values.join(', '));
```

Comment: wouldn't it be : `var values = [], i;  
    for (i=0; i < 4;`  ?